# How to debug Firefox running from Windows service without ability to set "Allow service to interact with desktop"

Tags: firefox, jenkins, windows-services, automated-tests

I have automated tests setup which runs product tests in 3 browsers on Windows: IE 11, Chrome and Firefox (55.0.3 and 56.0.b7 were tried).
Manual run of tests works fine in all 3 browsers on the particular machine from particular user.

But if to run test using Jenkins slave running as Windows service from the same user, it works just with IE 11 and Chrome but fails with Firefox in the beginning.
Since Firefox is running from Windows service, there is no UI so I can't get what Firefox needs to get working.

I suspect that it hangs on some dialog like "Do you want to make me default browser?".
The particular setting is set to false in `about:config` for test profile but I was not able to find full list of such dialogs anywhere so I can't be sure that I've switched off all of them.

The main problem is that I can't see the issue: if I enable "Allow service to interact with desktop" for Jenkins slave, it gets working fine. Unfortunately, it is not possible to keep this option on for Jenkins slave since it has to run from particular user and there is no such option for the case.

Any idea how to debug what Firefox needs if you can't see the browser ui?
I've already tried to capture Firefox log using `NSPR_LOG_MODULES=all:5` and
`NSPR_LOG_FILE=<path-to-log>` but did not find any clue in the log.

What else can I do to find the root cause of the issue?
Can I connect to running Firefox remotely to see what it does or waits for?
Can I capture other logs probably?

**Some test setup details**

Build system is based on Jenkins and the particular step is running via Jenkins slave on Windows 7 machine running as Windows service from particular user.
The tests are node.js scripts which do the following steps:

1. run local http server to serve test page and resources it uses
2. run browser to load the page (for Firefox it is the following command line:
   `<full path to firefox>/firefox.exe -no-remote -profile <full-path-for-prepared-profile> <url-to-test-page>`)
3. wait for http request from browser to confirm that page is
   ready to run tests
4. ...

In case of failure the request on step 3 never comes so it looks like Firefox can't load the page due to unknown reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long-long-long investigation my colleague found the root cause and how to fix it (to work it around if to be more precise).

It appeared that in such condition [Bug1400637](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1400637) happens and to work it around in Firefox v57.0 it requires to set `security.sandbox.content.level` to `4` in `about:config`.

Also I've learned that in Firefox for issues like this it could be worth to look at `about:crashes`, it helps to find root causes and even find the solution.